# Solving equations of the form $\sin (f_1(x)) = \alpha \sin(f_2(x))$ for linear $f_1$ and $f_2$, with $0<\alpha<1$

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods

I wish to solve an equation of the form,
$$\sin (f_1(x)) = \alpha \sin(f_2(x))$$
where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are given and linear, and $0<\alpha<1$ .

This came up in an analysis of triangulating one's position with respect to three stationary beacons.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of coefficients in $f_1,f_2$? What general solution procedure do you envision? Most numerical packages have root-finders for scalar equation, what are your obstacles in applying them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f_1(x) = a_1x + b_1, f_2(x) = a_2x + b_2$. Let $$g(x) = \sin(a_1x + b_1) - \alpha\sin(a_2x + b_2)$$
You are looking for points where $g(x) = 0$. Newton's method is useful for this.
$$g'(x) = a_1\cos(a_1x + b_1) - a_2\alpha\cos(a_2x + b_2)$$
The iteration equation is
$$x_{n+1} = x_n -\frac{\sin(a_1x_n + b_1) - \alpha\sin(a_2x_n + b_2)}{a_1\cos(a_1x_n + b_1) - a_2\alpha\cos(a_2x_n + b_2)}$$

Start with an initial guess, such as $x_0 = 0$, and it will take only a few iterations for it to settle down on a root of $g(x)$.